# Filtering the droplist of property in User Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have added the following property in a user control

```
private Control _associatedControl = new Control();
[Description("Sets Asociated Control"),
 Category("EzData"),
 DefaultValue(""),
 Browsable(true)]
public Control AssociatedControl
{
    get => _associatedControl;
    set
    {
        _associatedControl = value;
    }
}
```

in design time the control list all the controls in the parent form.
My question  how can I make the list includes only the controls in certain Domains (other user controls I designed ).

Answer (score 0):

The designer fills the list based on the type of the property. For example, if the property type is `Button`, the list will contains only button controls.

You can use a base type (or an interface) for your controls and then declare the property with the same type. This way, the designer will show only the objects having that type (or the interface) in the list.

For example, declaring the property:

```
public MyBaseControl AssociatedControl { get; set; }
```

Then the designer will list all instances of controls which are derived from `MyBaseControl`.